# Sending data in a POST message to a RESTful web service

Tags: python, web-services, rest

I need to send some JSON data in a POST message to a RESTful webservice.

Which python module should I be using for this?  Is there some sample code I can refer to?

Answer (score 3):

Which bit are you having trouble with? The JSON, or the POST?

For JSON, the `json` module has been included in Python since version 2.5. Just do `json.dumps(my_data)` to convert a data variable to JSON.

For the POST, there are various modules in the standard library, but the best bet is to install the third-party [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) library.

Answer (score 0):

here is what I've used for post and get requests

```
import httplib
connection =  httplib.HTTPConnection('192.168.38.38:6543')
body_content = 'abcd123456xyz'
connection.request('POST', '/foo/bar/baa.html', body_content)
postResult = connection.getresponse()

connection.request('GET', '/foo/bar/baa.html')
response = connection.getresponse()
getResult = response.read()
```

It does same as this sequence of CLI commands:

```
curl -X POST -d "abcd123456xyz" 192.168.38.38:6543/foo/bar/baa.html
curl 192.168.38.38:6543/foo/bar/baa.html
```

Comment: In my application I then compare body_content and getResult to check if data were updated on a server.
It does same as this:
curl -X POST -d "abcd123456xyz" http://192.168.38.38:6543/foo/bar/baa.html 
and then:
curl http://192.168.38.38:6543/foo/bar/baa.html

Answer (score 0):

Requests is probably the best library for the job.  It certainly beats urllib and urllib2.  You can get it and see an example at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests
or you can just install it with "pip install requests"

There's a few more examples using the Github API with both the requests library and others at https://github.com/issackelly/Consuming-Web-APIs-with-Python-Talk